# Factorization of density matrices

Tags: quantum-entanglement, density-operator, time-evolution, trace, open-quantum-systems

I'm currently reading through the following document about quantum noise and open quantum systems: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse599d/06wi/lecturenotes13.pdf. On page 6 of the document, it is analyzing a bipartite system $\mathscr A\otimes\mathscr B$, and analyzing what happens from the perspective of the system $\mathscr A$ ("tracing out" the degrees of freedom of $\mathscr B$) if the entire system is subjected to a unitary evolution $U$. I then came across the following line:

> The new density matrix after the evolution for the $\mathscr A$ subsystem is$$\rho'_\mathscr A=\text{Tr}_\mathscr B\left[U\rho U^\dagger\right]=\text{Tr}_\mathscr B\left[U(\rho_\mathscr A\otimes\rho_\mathscr B)U^\dagger\right].$$

The text goes on to derive the familiar equations regarding the unitary evolution of half a bipartite system. My question is: why were we able to factor the system density matrix $\rho$ as $\rho_\mathscr A\otimes\rho_\mathscr B$? Doesn't this imply that the system is unentangled? And to my (limited) knowledge, the theory of open quantum systems seems to deal extensively with situations in which decoherence is caused by *entanglement* between a system and its surroundings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an assumption. But an assumption of that kind is necessary to derive an effective dynamics for the system alone. Whether such an effective description is correct (and to which accuracy) is a different question, and depends on the scenario considered.

(Note that this is precisely what is written in the document: It says "we have assume[d] that the initial state is separable")

Comment: I see; that makes sense. So that means this approach doesn't work whenever the system is entangled with its environment? From the OQS readings that I have done so far, this kind of entanglement seems to happen quite a lot.

Comment: @slithy_tove Of course, this entanglement is very relevant -- but it is "lost" in the environment, because the environment is large. If this does not happen, we cannot obtain a dynamics for the system alone.